# How to extract value of the child in expandablelistview with onChildClickListener?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-intent, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view which is getting generated dynamically and the child list holds another set of values, I need to set an onChildClickListener on the child list so that a web intent is passed with the specific URL held in the data of every child list. Therefore I need to access the values of the child list on every OnChildClickListener event.

Please help!!
PS: please comment if any further explanation or code is required.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();

        onPostCreate(new Bundle());
        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

        try
        {   
            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");

            else
            {
                JSONArray jarray = data.getJSONArray("data");   

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jarray.get(i);

                    String taskId = obj.getString("taskId");    
                    String taskSub = obj.getString("taskSubject");



                    String v1= "Task Subject :"+taskSub;

                    Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();   
                    groupData.add(curGroupMap);   
                    curGroupMap.put(TAG,v1); 

                    List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();      

                        Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();   
                        children.add(curChildMap);  
                        curChildMap.put(TAG,"               "+taskId);
                        childData.add(children); 

        }
                //ADAPTER SETTINGS
                  mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(           
                            Search.this,               
                            groupData,       
                            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,       
                            new String[] { TAG },     
                            new int[] { android.R.id.text1},   

                            childData,            
                            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,    
                            new String[] { TAG },     
                            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }  
                            );      
                    setListAdapter(mAdapter); 
                    getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(Search.this);           
        }
        } 
        catch (JSONException je)
        {
            je.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + je.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                int childPosition, long id) 
        {               
            Uri webpage = Uri.parse("URL"+taskId);

              //I want to add the taskId i am extracting in my dynamic expandable list in the URL, therefore each URL will be unique according to the taskId.

            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(webIntent, 0);
            boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
                if (isIntentSafe) 
                {
                 startActivity(webIntent);
                }

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

add listener for child click listener

```
getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

add code for click listener.

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPos, int childPos, long id) {
   // use groupPosition and childPosition to get the item data from adapter.
   return true;
}
```

add this code in adapter

```
@Override
//gets the name of each item
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {         
   return dataList.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1);
}
```

Comment: I want to extract the VALUE held at the specific group and child position. The above code will just return the positions whereas I want the values held there.

Comment: Could you post the code on how to extract the data from the adapter because that bit is what im specifically looking for.

Comment: Look at my answer now i was edited it now. you have to return data by passing position values when you click on child item.

Comment: I am assuming that i and i1 are group and child position respectively. Need a little help with what mParent is because it is throwing an error if im trying to fix the expandablelistview parent there.

Comment: mParent means it's a data list like ArrayList<Object> passing from activity to Adapter , what you want to display in expandable listview..

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code, please see and let me know what the required code might be.

Comment: you're not using CustomAdapter for pop up data in Expandable list view.. look at this tutorial http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html

Comment: I am dynamically generating my expandable list view and thats why im using a SimpleExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: whatever it may be it's easy to get data when you use Custom Adapter. otherwise try any methods are available to get data from default.try i am not sure about that..

Comment: I condensed my solution code down to `String url = ***.get(groupPosition).getItemList().get(childPosition);` but im still not sure what to pass instead of *** specific to my code. Help!

Comment: try like this `parent.get(groupPosition).getItemList().get(childPosition);`. here parent means look at my answer .

Comment: I have the same code and variables, not working. It is not able to understand the get() function along with parent then.

Comment: Even if you can provide some pointers on how I can access the dynamic value of taskId from the onChildClickListener function, it will be of great help!

Comment: come to discussion chat i will help you.. my suggestion is better to create one Custom adapter. anyway click on discussion chat.

Comment: Cant! My office internet wont allow that. Can you please study the code and suggest any other way around. I would really appreciate a solution with SimpleExpandableListAdapter itself.

Comment: chat means in stackover flow only, ok leave it.better to use Custom adapter for easy to reach your requirement.try to do that from my above link, let me know if you face any problems..

Comment: I know that, the internet is blocked for any chatting portals. Thankyou for your time anyway!